# jQuery Animate to Auto Height and back

Tags: jquery

There is a list of elements and I need to expand it on click on the first element and then roll up to previous height (on the click on the first element too).

```js
var $body = $('body');
 
 function languagesListDropdown() {
  $body.on('click', '#language li a.chosen', function (e) {
   var $languagesList = $('#language');
   
   if (!$languagesList.hasClass('opened')) {
    var curHeight = $languagesList.height();
    $languagesList.css('height', 'auto');
    var autoHeight = $languagesList.height();
    $languagesList.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 300, function(){
     $(this).addClass('opened');
    });
   } else {
   }
   
   
   return false;
  });
 }
 
 languagesListDropdown();
```

```css
.language {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid #f6e8d9;
}

.language:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: #636264 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 6px 4px 0 4px;
  content: '';
}

.language > li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 28px;
}

.language > li a {
  display: block;
  height: 28px;
  padding: 7px 20px 0 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #636264;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="language" id="language">
     <li>
      <a href="#" class="chosen">es</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">en</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">fr</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">lat</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
```

My function expands the list, but I don't know how to roll up it to the previous height?

Comment: sorry if I'm bold, but consider this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sq6sh0e1/1/  isn't it far more easier to use jQuery's slideToggle function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty, but you can store the original height in a variable and reference it.

```
var $body = $('body');
var original_height = $('#language').height();
function languagesListDropdown() {
    $body.on('click', '#language li a.chosen', function (e) {
        var $languagesList = $('#language');
        var curHeight = $languagesList.height();
        if (!$languagesList.hasClass('opened')) {
            $languagesList.css('height', 'auto');
            var autoHeight = $languagesList.height();
            $languagesList.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 300, function(){
                $(this).addClass('opened');
            });
        } else {
            $languagesList.height(curHeight).animate({height: original_height}, 300, function(){
                $(this).removeClass('opened');
            });
        }


        return false;
    });
}

languagesListDropdown();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

One problem with JavaScript or CSS transitions is that, `height: auto` or `width: auto` **cannot** be animated! So you can do one thing:

```
$languagesList.css('height', 'auto');
$languagesList.css('height', $languagesList.height());
```

This will compute the `auto` height of the element. You can make use of this in the animation, by either storing them inside the `.data()` object or using a variable.

Your final code will be:

```
var $body = $('body');

$('#language').data("orig-height", $('#language').height())

function languagesListDropdown() {
    $body.on('click', '#language li a.chosen', function (e) {
        var $languagesList = $('#language');

        if (!$languagesList.hasClass('opened')) {
            var curHeight = $languagesList.height();
            $languagesList.css('height', 'auto');
            var autoHeight = $languagesList.height();
            $languagesList.height(curHeight).animate({
                height: autoHeight
            }, 300, function () {
                $(this).addClass('opened');
            });
        } else {
            var curHeight = $languagesList.height();
            orig_height = $('#language').data("orig-height");
            $languagesList.height(curHeight).animate({
                height: orig_height
            }, 300, function () {
                $(this).removeClass('opened');
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
}

languagesListDropdown();
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mgLvz8sw/**

Comment: Actually my code works and you can check it. I just don't know how to write other part in `else`.